# How to Draw a circle displaying a number in flex 

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I am flex newbie , so please forgive me if i am not using the right words to ask the following question. I want to know if there is a way to draw a circle which shows a number , like for ex. [Graduated Circles](http://wardley.org/kites/freestyle/technical/gradcirc.html) representing its radius to show it's relevance. Is there a component which already do so , if not what is the best way to do this.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example on how you could do it (to be continued to achieve your particular needs)

```
package  
{
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;  
    import flash.text.TextField;    
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;   

    public class LabeledCircle extends Sprite 
    {
        private var textField:TextField;

        public function LabeledCircle(radius:Number, label:String = "")
        {
            // Prepares the textField

            var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            textFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;

            textField = new TextField();
            textField.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;

            addChild(textField);

            // Sets the default parameters

            this.radius = radius;
            this.label = label;
        }


        public function set radius(radius:Number):void
        {
            // redraws the circle
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.beginFill(0x000000, .5);
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);

            // recenters the textfield depending on the radius
            textField.width = radius * 2;
            textField.x = -radius;
        }


        public function set label(label:String):void
        {
            textField.text = label;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) has a component which is similar to the concentric circle example in the link you have posted. See Layouts > CirclePack in the [demo](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo).

I am not yet sure what you mean by 'associating a number'. Try [this](http://www.tom-carden.co.uk/2008/10/01/text-along-a-path-in-flash/): Rendering text on a path.

Comment: Thanks dirkgently , but mainly i want to know how to associate a number with any of the circles , be it with any of the example for which i gave a link above.

Comment: like for example , i want to have something like this http://www.chicagocarto.com/images/quadcities.jpg ,but i would like to have number size to be in proportion with the size of the circle. Going through the link u posted , looks like i should be looking for how to embed fonts inside a circle.

Comment: Yes, alongwith font embedding, you will need to scale them according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

- Actionscript Drawing API - example [here](http://flash-creations.com/notes/dynamic_drawingapi.php)
- [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/) - Graphics framework which makes the Drawing API easier to use and includes a circle class